# Accessing read-only Google Storage buckets from Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

I am trying to access Google Storage bucket from a Hadoop cluster deployed in Google Cloud using the `bdutil` script. It fails if bucket access is read-only.

What am I doing:

1. Deploy a cluster with

   ```
   bdutil deploy -e datastore_env.sh
   ```
2. On the master:

   ```
   vgorelik@vgorelik-hadoop-m:~$ hadoop fs -ls gs://pgp-harvard-data-public 2>&1 | head -10
   14/08/14 14:34:21 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.2.8-hadoop1
   14/08/14 14:34:25 WARN gcsio.GoogleCloudStorage: Repairing batch of 174 missing directories.
   14/08/14 14:34:26 ERROR gcsio.GoogleCloudStorage: Failed to repair some missing directories.
   java.io.IOException: Multiple IOExceptions.
   java.io.IOException: Multiple IOExceptions.
       at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.createCompositeException(GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.java:61)
       at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.createEmptyObjects(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:361)
       at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.createEmptyObjects(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:372)
       at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.listObjectInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:914)
       at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.listObjectInfo(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:455)
   ```

Looking at [GCS Java source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java), it seems that Google Cloud Storage Connector for Hadoop needs empty "directory" objects, which it can create by its own if the bucket is writeable; otherwise it fails. Setting `fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable=false` leads to "Error retrieving object" error.

Is it possible to use read-only buckets as MR job input somehow?

I use `gsutil` for files upload. Can it be forced to create these empty objects on file upload?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use a read-only Google Cloud Storage bucket as input for a Hadoop job.

For example, I have run this job many times:

```
./hadoop-install/bin/hadoop \
  jar ./hadoop-install/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar \
  -input gs://pgp-harvard-data-public/hu0*/*/*/*/ASM/master* \
  -mapper cgi-mapper.py -file cgi-mapper.py --numReduceTasks 0 \
  -output gs://big-data-roadshow/output
```

This accesses the same read-only bucket you mention in your example above.

The difference between our examples is that mine ends with a glob (`*`), which the Google Cloud Storage Connector for Hadoop is able to expand without needing to use any of the "placeholder" directory objects.

I recommend you use `gsutil` to explore the read-only bucket you're interested in (since it doesn't need the "placeholder" objects) and once you have a glob expression that returns the list of objects you want processed, use that glob expression in your `hadoop` command.

The answer to your second question ("Can `gsutil` be forced to create these empty objects on file upload") is currently "no".